# First select too slow

Tags: postgresql

Run the machine(centos release 6.7 (Final)) in the 4G above postgresql-9.4，    There is a partition table, each partition table about 10 million records in the select, the first query query particularly slow, about 15 seconds, but second times in the OK, I don't know why. Need help。

Posted below is my SQL and execution plan

```
     explain SELECT
      pos_uuid,
pos_bus_uuid,
pos_gather_time,
pos_real_time_status,
pos_odometer,
pos_drv_ic_card
FROM   t_bus_position_20160306_20160308  WHERE  pos_gather_time >=  '2016-03-06 00:08:00' AND pos_gather_time <='2016-03-06 23:59:59' and  pos_is_offset = 't'  and pos_bus_uuid ='b478193370f24b8f9fe1' ORDER BY pos_gather_time ;
                                                                                                                    QUERY PLAN
```

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
Sort  (cost=94141.44..94176.57 rows=14052 width=145)
   Sort Key: pos_gather_time
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on t_bus_position_20160306_20160308  (cost=1039.36..93173.36 rows=14052 width=145)
         Recheck Cond: (((pos_bus_uuid)::text = 'b478193370f24b8f9fe1'::text) AND (pos_gather_time >= '2016-03-06 00:08:00'::timestamp withou
t time zone) AND (pos_gather_time <= '2016-03-06 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone))
         Filter: pos_is_offset
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_check_index  (cost=0.00..1035.85 rows=28103 width=0)
               Index Cond: (((pos_bus_uuid)::text = 'b478193370f24b8f9fe1'::text) AND (pos_gather_time >= '2016-03-06 00:08:00'::timestamp wi
thout time zone) AND (pos_gather_time <= '2016-03-06 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone))

It is several important parameters of the configuration file
shared_buffers =2GB 
huge_pages = try                            
temp_buffers = 16MB                     
work_mem =128MB         
maintenance_work_mem =512MB     
max_stack_depth = 8MB           
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix  
checkpoint_segments = 32    
max_connections = 100
seq_page_cost = 1.0         
random_page_cost = 4        
cpu_tuple_cost = 0.01       
cpu_index_tuple_cost = 0.005        
cpu_operator_cost = 0.0025      
effective_cache_size = 2GB  



      \d t_bus_position_20160303_20160305
           Table "public.t_bus_position_20160303_20160305"
         Column         |              Type              | Modifiers 
------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------
 pos_uuid               | character varying(20)          | not null
 pos_line_uuid          | character varying(20)          | 
 pos_line_type          | character varying(20)          | 
 pos_bus_uuid           | character varying(20)          | 
 pos_dev_uuid           | character varying(20)          | 
 pos_sta_uuid           | character varying(20)          | 
 pos_drv_ic_card        | character varying(30)          | 
 pos_lng                | character varying(30)          | 
 pos_lat                | character varying(30)          | 
 pos_bus_speed          | character varying(20)          | 
 pos_real_time_status   | character varying(20)          | 
 pos_gather_time        | timestamp(6) without time zone | 
 pos_storage_time       | timestamp(6) without time zone | 
 pos_is_offset          | character varying(20)          | 
 pos_is_overspeed       | character varying(1)           | 
 pos_cursor_over_ground | character varying(20)          | 
 pos_all_alarms         | character varying(30)          | 
 pos_is_in_station      | character varying(1)           | 
 pos_closed_alarms      | character varying(30)          | 
 pos_dis_to_pre_i       | integer                        | 
 pos_odometer_i         | bigint                         | 
 pos_relative_location  | real                           | 
 pos_dis_to_pre         | real                           | 
 pos_odometer           | double precision               | 
 pos_gather_date        | date                           | 
Indexes:
    "tp_20160303_20160305_pos_uuid_idx" UNIQUE, btree (pos_uuid)
    "tp_20160303_20160305_pos_bus_gather_date_idx" btree ((pos_bus_uuid::text || extract_date(pos_gather_time)))
    "tp_20160303_20160305_pos_bus_gather_idx" btree (pos_bus_uuid, extract_date(pos_gather_time))
    "tp_20160306_20160308_pos_bus_gather_time_idx" btree (pos_gather_time, pos_gather_time DESC)
Check constraints:
    "t_bus_position_20160303_20160305_pos_gather_time_check" CHECK (pos_gather_time >= '2016-03-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone AND
 pos_gather_time < '2016-03-06 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
Inherits: t_bus_position


 **This is the is Boolean pos_is_offset implementation plan**
explain    SELECT
pos_uuid,
pos_bus_uuid,
pos_gather_time,
pos_real_time_status,
pos_odometer,
pos_drv_ic_card
FROM   t_bus_position_20160306_20160308  WHERE  pos_gather_time >=  '2016-03-06 00:08:00' AND pos_gather_time <='2016-03-06 23:59:59' and  pos_is_offset = 't'  and pos_bus_uuid ='b478193370f24b8f9fe1' ORDER BY pos_gather_time ;
                                                                                                                QUERY PLAN                   

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=94141.44..94176.57 rows=14052 width=145)
   Sort Key: pos_gather_time
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on t_bus_position_20160306_20160308  (cost=1039.36..93173.36 rows=14052 width=145)
         Recheck Cond: (((pos_bus_uuid)::text = 'b478193370f24b8f9fe1'::text) AND (pos_gather_time >= '2016-03-06 00:08:00'::timestamp withou
t time zone) AND (pos_gather_time <= '2016-03-06 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone))
         Filter: pos_is_offset
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_check_index  (cost=0.00..1035.85 rows=28103 width=0)
               Index Cond: (((pos_bus_uuid)::text = 'b478193370f24b8f9fe1'::text) AND (pos_gather_time >= '2016-03-06 00:08:00'::timestamp wi
thout time zone) AND (pos_gather_time <= '2016-03-06 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone))
(7 rows)
```

Comment: Could you provide the table structure / indexes on the table?

Comment: OK, I'll provide the table structure right away.

Comment: Could you put the table definition in ordered format? Its pretty hard to read this way.

Comment: sorry，i first uses tackoverflow，Not yet familiar

Comment: much better.. thanks

Comment: OK, I've adjusted the format.

Comment: Part of the index is my own test, this can be completely deleted，I don't understand why his timestamp will spend so long time, and have been out of the index scan, why the data is still so slow

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. It looks like the spoiler here is the `pos_is_offset` column, which is the only field that isn't a part of the index being used. Is this a very important query (enough to modify the index and add that boolean as well) that might help speeding up the query a lot.
2. Queries running slow the first time, and faster in subsequent runs, is a clear indication that the table is being read from the disk, and a caching affects speed for the subsequent runs. Speeding up the query gets difficult, especially if you're low on RAM + large data-sets.

Additionally, do you really need 14k rows in the output? Or are the tables not frequently `ANALYSE`'d? If the row-count when running an `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` gives numbers too far away, probably you'd need to `ANALYSE` that table as well.

Comment: no,pos_is_offset is  test table,Is not a production table, I re paste the production table, you look at

Comment: Probably every pos_bus_uuid record is similar, are so many, as for the analyze table I often do, this query is not very often, but look up to feel very slow

Comment: Is pos_is_offset a test table? I am referring to your `EXPLAIN QUERY` which has this in the `WHERE` condition ( ... `AND  pos_is_offset = 't' AND` ... ), I was talking about that column to be included in the index.

Comment: Unrelated, if `pos_is_offset` is a `BOOLEAN`, you should remove the `varchar(20)` and make it a `BOOLEAN` type instead, but that depends on what kind of data you have in there.

Comment: i understand what you said,OK, I now give you posted pos_is_offset  is boolean execution plan, if the query performance is good, I call it the production table also changed

Comment: Just to clarify, converting `pos_is_offset` to `BOOLEAN` is good, but *optional*. .... 

What should make performance better is adding `pos_is_offset` to the Index. Importantly, I think an `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` would be more interesting.